# El teclado se superpone al contenido de Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy creando una aplicación en compose sobre una lista de tareas o recordatorios, lo que muestro es la pantalla o layout para crear un nuevo recordatorio, y el inconveniente con el que me encuentro surge cuando presiono el teclado, este oculta los botones, lo que quisiera lograr es que los botones se pongan debajo donde termina la altura del teclado(Como indico en la segunda imagen y en la tercera indico el resultado esperado).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(ScaffoldBackGroundColor), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Nuevo Recordatorio",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            color = Color.Black.copy(0.8F),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp)
        )

        CustomTextField(
            value = noteInput,
            onChange = { note -> setNoteValue(note) },
            placeholder = "Nota",
            height = 170.dp
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {

                Button(
                    onClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                    shape = ShapeDefaults.Small,
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Cancelar", color = Color.Black)
                }
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        todoViewModel.addTodo(
                            TodoItem(
                                todoViewModel.state.value.last().id + 1,
                                noteInput,
                                LocalDate.now().toString(),
                                false
                            )
                        )
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    },
                    shape = ShapeDefaults.Small,
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Guardar", color = Color.Gray)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **RESULTADO ESPERADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias opciones, puedes realizarlo como se realiza en Android nativo usando la propiedad : `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` en tu `<activity>` dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

También puedes definir en onCreate() SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        
        setContent { 
          ...
          ...
          ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excelente, Muchas Gracias por el aporte ! 